# Using a command's output to determine the name of the file to redirect output to

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I want to run `smartctl -a`, and use the device serial number from that output as the name of the file to store the output in.  I know this can be done by invoking `smartctl` twice, and slicing up the output with suitable text manipulation.  Is there a way to do it with only a single invocation of `smartctl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the output of `smartctl` into a variable and use it as many times as you like.

```
smartctl_output=$(smartctl -a /dev/sda)
serial_number=$(printf %s "$smartctl_output" | awk 'sub(/^Serial Number: */,"")')
printf %s "$smartctl_output" >"$serial_number.txt"
```

Comment: I suppose `smartctl` doesn't output multiple lines. What about programs that do, since this will string out all the new lines? A temporary file would retain the newlines.

Comment: @muru `smartctl` outputs multiple lines. Command substitution only strips out newlines at the end, it doesn't mash lines together.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't quoted the variable while using `printf`. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the output of `smartctl -a` in a temporary file and then do the double parse on that. This makes testing your script fast (generate the temporary file once, comment out the call to `smartctl`, adjust your parser until they are satisfactory, then uncomment the `smartctl` line.

Alternatively you can use `pee` to pipe the output of `smartctl -a` into two programs, but you would still need a temporary file from the one processs, that can be renamed with the serial number as found by the other.

Comment: A temporary file? Why would you use a temporary file?